# Remove access to location in phone gap and cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Hi every body U recently we create a new App in android with cordova and we want to remove `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`  but we doesn't know which plugin related to this permission , this is `config.xml` file :

```
 <!-- PhoneGap core plugins -->
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen"        source="npm" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay"              value="3000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen"           value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreen"                   value="www/res/screen/android" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio"      value="true" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status"      source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device"              source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion"       source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation"  source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs"             source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file"                source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer"       source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization"       source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser"        source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar"           source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration"           source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist"           source="npm" />
```

please help us to remove related plugin . thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin you are looking for is `cordova-plugin-device-orientation`. It uses the `permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` in its `config.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

oh , you can simply remove `cordova-plugin-device-orientation` , this plugin is related to location service . I hope this help you ;)